# Nullpointer with Checkbox.isChecked

Tags: java, android, checkbox, nullpointerexception

Hi i am getting a nullpointer at line 493, marked in below code.
Can somebody assist in solving this? I almost know 100% it is the checkbox (nieuwbel).
But i can't get rid of the Exception.

Thank you in advance.

```
@Override     
protected void onPause() { 
    MyBeltegoed dialog = new MyBeltegoed (this, new OnReadyListenerBeltegoed()); 
    nieuwbel = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel); 
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();   
    e.putBoolean(PREF_BOOL, nieuwbel.isChecked());  <----- Nullpointer             
    e.commit();          
    Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    super.onPause();    
}
```

Comment: your `isChecked()` is alway going to be false you realize that ??? secondly put a freaking break point and just check as what is null.Do not just assume that `nieuwbel` is null and even it is whats the problem you are facing in debugging in . It's a nerve wreckinglying lazy question.

Comment: what is the value of nieuwbel, PREF_BOOL and e???

One of these are null???

Comment: Hi Pedro Rainho, already solved.
Thank you.
I set the following in onCreate:
MyBeltegoed dialog = new MyBeltegoed (this, new OnReadyListenerBeltegoed());  
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
nieuwbel = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the content view correctly? Ensure that you are using your created R class, not the default android R class.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

EDIT:

You need to set the content view for the dialog, too.

```
@Override     
protected void onPause() { 
  MyBeltegoed dialog = new MyBeltegoed (this, new OnReadyListenerBeltegoed()); 

  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); <-- add this

  nieuwbel = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel); 
  Editor e = mPrefs.edit();   
  e.putBoolean(PREF_BOOL, nieuwbel.isChecked());           
  e.commit();          
  Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
  super.onPause();    
}
```

`custom_dialog` is the dialog that contains nieuwbel. (from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Comment: Also in the dialog? It needs to load the view that contains nieuwbel.

Comment: The checkbox nieuwbel is in a different xml file called layout.
So if i did setContentView (R.id.nieuwbel); in the onPause it should be ok?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check that `nieuwbel` is not `null` after attempting to get it. [`findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) might not find what you are looking for:

> **Returns** The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null

Try this:

```
@Override     
protected void onPause() { 
    MyBeltegoed dialog = new MyBeltegoed (this, new OnReadyListenerBeltegoed()); 
    nieuwbel = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.nieuwbel); 
    if (nieuwbel != null) {
        Editor e = mPrefs.edit();   
        e.putBoolean(PREF_BOOL, nieuwbel.isChecked());             
        e.commit();          
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to save settings!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onPause();    
}
```

Logcat forceclose:

```
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.sencide/com.sencide.AndroidLogin} did not call through to super.onPause()
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3854)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2341)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-31 22:57:36.618: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi ObscureRobot, yes i know but i don`t know where the error mide be?
Can you help?, just tell me what you need to know please.

Comment: You will need to trace your logic to make sure that R.id.nieuwbel contains the proper id by the time `onPause()` is called.

Comment: Ok, nullpointer is gone but now i get a forceclose, please see edited code.

Comment: @Lars you know `R` is not null, or `R.id` would have thrown a NPE. You know `R.id` is not null, or `R.id.nieuwbel` would have thrown a NPE. It is possible `R.id.nieuwbel` is null, but you explicitly check for that. This leaves one alternative:the key  (`R.id.nieuwbel`) is not null, but simply has no value in the `findViewById` backing map.